# Update and animate a gradient in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to create an app that has a gradient background which changes as people slide up and down on the screen. I wanted the gradient to be of radial type which is why I used a Core Graphics instead of a `CAGradientLayer`.

My view controller has a property for a subclass of `UIView` which has the following implementation for its drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect
{
    self.alpha = 1.0;

    // Draw radial gradient here using C language
    CGPoint startCenter, endCenter;

    startCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetHeight(rect));

    endCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetHeight(rect));


    //radial gradient radius;
    CGFloat startRadius = 0.17 * CGRectGetHeight(rect);
    CGFloat endRadius = 1.04 * CGRectGetHeight(rect);

    //gradient locations.    
    CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 0.8};

    //gradient color components.
    CGFloat components[8] = {
                              232/255.0, 249/255.0, 229/255.0, 1.0,
                              133/255.0, 174/255.0, 127/255.0, 1.0,
                             };

    //Drawing code.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    //Get RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    //create gradient.
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(space, components, locations, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    //draw gradient.
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, startCenter, startRadius,endCenter,endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);



    _contextToSave = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  // useless

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
```

What I want is to be able to update the gradient so I was thinking about using properties or instance variables in my components `CGFloat` array and then animating the change but I have no idea how to do that.

I know that I should wait for a gesture recognizer and depending on the gesture, adjust the gradient but since my problem was not so much when to update but rather how to update, I decided to try to update the gradient in my `viewDidAppear` method inside my `ViewController` and nothing happened.

Just to try to create an change of gradient and an animation, I tried this following code in the `viewDidAppear` of my `ViewController`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:6.0 animations:^{

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat colorsComponents[8] = {
        145/255.0, 149/255.0, 229/255.0, 1.0,
        133/255.0, 74/255.0, 27/255.0, 1.0,
    };

    CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 0.8};

    //CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint startCenter, endCenter;

    startCenter = CGPointMake(0.5 * gradientView.frame.size.width, gradientView.frame.size.height);

    startCenter = endCenter;

    CGFloat startRadius = 0.17 * gradientView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat endRadius = 1.04 * gradientView.frame.size.height;


    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colorsComponents, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(_subclassofView.contextToSave, gradient, startCenter, startRadius, endCenter, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);

}];
```

Thank your for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do custom animations have a look at:

- [this article (Animating Pie Slices Using a Custom CALayer)](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/) by Pavan Podila
- [this video (Animating Custom Layer Properties)](http://vimeo.com/44986916) by Rob Napier.

Together they teach you a lot of good ways to do custom animations.

Comment: Thanks! I'm watching the second link right now and I'm learning quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In any case this helps any beginner iOS coder, I'll share the solution to my question. I'm not sure sure this is the most elegant solution or the one with the best performance but it seems to work for now... Basically inside the drawrect of my subclass of UIView I changed all of the components values (the values who define the color with RGB and alpha) to values that exist in a property. This property is a NSMutableArray which I use in my view controller to change its values and then call [self.subview setNeedsDisplay].

Comment: You are right, not the most elegant nor the most performant solution. Have a look at the links in my answer. They should help you.